# Jumbotron background image not responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, media-queries

When testing my website in the browser, my jumbotron (bg image), image opacity and caption divs not scaling properly. I'm trying to make it all responsive without showing any white spaces. I've set my heights for each div that I just mentioned and maybe that could be the cause.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>


        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>The Portfolio of Jason Murray</title>


        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link id="orginal" href="css/default-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body>
        <!--=========== HEADER SECTION ================-->
        <header id="header">
          <!-- BEGIN MENU -->
          <div class="menu_area">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"> 
              <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- FOR MOBILE VIEW COLLAPSED BUTTON -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- LOGO -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Jason<span>Murray</span></a>
              </div>

              <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul id="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right main_nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>               
                  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>                           
                </ul>           
              </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
              </div>     
            </nav>  
          </div><!-- END MENU -->
        </header>
         <!--=========== END HEADER SECTION ================-->

        <!--=========== MAIN CONTENT SECTION ================-->
        <div class="jumbotron">         
            <div class="container">
                <div class="image_opacity"></div> 
                <div class="caption">
                    <h2>Front-End</h2> 
                    <h2>Web Developer</h2>
                    <p>Hi, I'm Jason Murray and I have a passion for building simplistic websites.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="caption_btn">Recent Work</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--=========== END MAIN CONTENT SECTION ================-->

        <!--=========== FOOTER SECTION================-->
         <footer id="footer">
           <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                 <div class="footer_left">
                   <p>&copy; 2015 <a href="index.html" target="_blank">Jason Murray Web Design</a>. All Rights Reserved</p>
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                 <div class="footer_right">
                   <ul class="social_nav">
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </footer>
        <!--=========== END FOOTER SECTION================-->
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

CSS:

```
body,html{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a{ 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2f2f2f;

}
a:focus{
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1,h2{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; 
}
h3,h4,h5,h6{
    font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;  
}

h2 {
  color: #313338;  
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 57px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
img{
 border:none;
}

/*--------------------*/
/* HEADER */
/*--------------------*/

#header{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

/*--------.menu_area-------- */
.menu_area{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-color: transparent;
  padding: 12px 0px;
}
.past-main {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding:6px 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;

}
#navbar{overflow-x: hidden;}

.navbar-brand {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  color: #fff !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2da2c8;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #2da2c8;
}
.navbar-brand > span {
  color: #2da2c8;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus { 
  color: #2da2c8;
}


/*---------------------*/
/* MAIN CONTENT - HOME */
/*---------------------*/
.jumbotron {
  background: url("../img/lucho-49.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-top: 75px;
  height: 305px;
}
.image_opacity{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #242434;
  margin-top: 75px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 305px;
  z-index: 9;
}
.caption {
  margin-top: 17%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
}
.caption > h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 12px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 90%;
}
.caption>p{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;    
}
.caption_btn{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.caption_btn:hover,.caption_btn:focus{
    border-color:#2da2c8;
    color: #2da2c8;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*----------------------*/
/* MAIN CONTENT - ABOUT */
/*----------------------*/

#about {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 80px 0px;
}
.about_area{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.heading{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}
.heading h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  margin-top: 65px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.heading p{
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.about_content{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}
.about_featured{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}
.panel-group .panel {
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.panel-group .panel + .panel {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.panel-default {
  border-color: transparent;
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #333;
  border: 0 none !important;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
.panel-title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #222;
  font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.panel-title a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.panel-default .in{ 
  padding-left:10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s; 
}
.panel-title a span{
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.panel-body { 
  border-top-color: transparent !important;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
.about_slider{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
.single_iteam{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
.single_iteam img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.about_slider .slick-dots li button:before {
  content: "•";
  font-size: 28px;  
}
.about_slider .slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.skills_area{
  background-color: #fff
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 350px;
  padding: 85px 0px;
  position: relative;
}
.skills{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
.heading h3 {
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 40px;
}
div[data-dimension] {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.circle-text{
  color: #000;
}
.single_skill{
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.single_skill > h4 {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/*--------------------------*/
/* MAIN CONTENT - PORTFOLIO */
/*--------------------------*/

/*------------------------*/
/* MAIN CONTENT - CONTACT */
/*------------------------*/

/*--------------------*/
/* FOOTER */
/*--------------------*/

#footer{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
.footer_left{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer_left > p {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.footer_left > p a {  
  font-weight: bold;
}
.footer_right{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}
.social_nav{
  text-align: center;  
}
.social_nav li{
  display: inline-block;
}
.social_nav li a {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.social_nav li a:hover{
  color: #2da2c8;
  border-color: #2da2c8; 
}

/*----------------------------------*/
/* RESPONSIVE STYLE - MEDIA QUERIES */
/*----------------------------------*/

/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
@media(min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
.navbar-brand {color: #fff !important;font-size: 26px;font-weight: bolder;font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {font-size: 12px;}
.jumbotron {background: url("../img/lucho-49.jpg") no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;-o-background-size: 100% 100%;background-size: 100% 100%;height: 592px;}
.image_opacity{background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #242434;margin-top: 75px;height: 592px;opacity: 0.8;width: 100%;}
.caption {margin-top: 40%;position: relative;text-align: center;z-index: 999;}
.caption > h2 {color: #ffffff;font-size: 25px;font-weight: 700;line-height: 20px;margin: 0 auto 10px;padding-bottom: 8px;text-align: center;text-transform: uppercase;width: 90%;}
.caption> p {color: #ffffff;font-size: 14px;}
.caption_btn{padding: 10px 15px;border: 2px solid #fff;color: #fff;font-size: 14px;display: inline-block;text-transform: uppercase;}
.caption_btn:hover,.caption_btn:focus {border-color:#2da2c8;color: #2da2c8;text-decoration: none;}
#footer{padding: 24px;}
#footer > .container > .row {margin-right: auto;}
.footer_left > p {font-size: 12px;text-align: center;}
.social_nav{text-align: center;}
}
/* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
@media(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
.navbar-brand {color: #fff !important;font-size: 30px;font-weight: bolder;font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {font-size: 13px;}
.jumbotron {background: url("../img/lucho-49.jpg") no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;-o-background-size: 100% 100%;background-size: 100% 100%;height: 816px;}
.image_opacity{background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #242434;margin-top: 75px;height: 816px;opacity: 0.8;width: 100%;}
.caption {margin-top: 28%;position: relative;text-align: center;z-index: 999;}
.caption > h2 {color: #ffffff;font-size: 45px;font-weight: 700;line-height: 56px;margin: 0 auto 10px;padding-bottom: 8px;text-align: center;text-transform: uppercase;width: 90%;}
.caption> p {color: #ffffff;font-size: 18px;}
.caption_btn{padding: 10px 15px;border: 2px solid #fff;color: #fff;font-size: 18px;display: inline-block;text-transform: uppercase;}
.caption_btn:hover,.caption_btn:focus {border-color:#2da2c8;color: #2da2c8;text-decoration: none;}
#footer{padding: 35px;}
#footer > .container {margin-left:-15px;margin-right:-15px;}
.footer_left > p {font-size: 13px;text-align: left;}
#footer .row {margin-left: -26px;}
.social_nav{text-align: right;margin-right: 12px;}
}

/* Landscape tablets and medium desktops */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
.navbar-brand {color: #fff !important;font-size: 33px;font-weight: bolder;font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;}
.container > .navbar-header {margin-left:8px;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {font-size: 14px;}
.navbar-right {margin-right:0px;}
.jumbotron {background: url("../img/lucho-49.jpg") no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;-o-background-size: 100% 100%;background-size: 100% 100%;height: 1024px;}
.image_opacity{background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #242434;margin-top: 75px;height: 1024px;opacity: 0.8;width: 100%;}
.caption {margin-top: 32%;position: relative;text-align: center;z-index: 999;}
.caption > h2 {color: #ffffff;font-size: 55px;font-weight: 700;line-height: 66px;margin: 0 auto 10px;padding-bottom: 8px;text-align: center;text-transform: uppercase;width: 90%;}
.caption> p {color: #ffffff;font-size: 19px;}
.caption_btn{padding: 10px 15px;border: 2px solid #fff;color: #fff;font-size: 18px;display: inline-block;text-transform: uppercase;}
.caption_btn:hover,.caption_btn:focus {border-color:#2da2c8;color: #2da2c8;text-decoration: none;}
#footer{padding: 35px;}
#footer > .container {margin-left:-15px;margin-right:-15px;}
.footer_left > p {font-size: 14px;text-align: left;}
.social_nav{text-align: right;margin-right: 18px;}
}

/* Large desktops and laptops */
@media(min-width: 1200px) {
.navbar-brand {color: #fff !important;font-size: 35px;font-weight: bolder;font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {font-size: 15px;}
.jumbotron {background: url("../img/lucho-49.jpg") no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;-o-background-size: 100% 100%;background-size: 100% 100%;height: 740px;}
.image_opacity {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #242434;margin-top: 75px;height: 740px;opacity: 0.8;width: 100%;}
.caption {margin-top: 10%;position: relative;text-align: center;z-index: 999;}
.caption > h2 {color: #ffffff;font-size: 65px;font-weight: 700;line-height: 76px;margin: 0 auto 10px;padding-bottom: 8px;text-align: center;text-transform: uppercase;width: 90%;}
.caption > p {color: #ffffff;font-size: 20px;}
.caption_btn {padding: 10px 15px;border: 2px solid #fff;color: #fff;font-size: 20px;display: inline-block;text-transform: uppercase;}
.caption_btn:hover,.caption_btn:focus {border-color:#2da2c8;color: #2da2c8;text-decoration: none;}
#footer{padding: 35px;}
.footer_left > p {font-size: 15px;text-align: left;}
.social_nav{text-align: right;}
}
```

Comment: I can help u with the ans but there too much code to understand.
Just draw a jsfiddle with a problem where i can look at exactly where the problem is and will find the solution accordingly.

Comment: I appreciate your help Niraj. https://jsfiddle.net/51v4jeLa/1/

Comment: i saw ur fiddle and based on the problem of background image not responsive i have made my jsfiddle solving the problem. Have a look at it any tell me whether its correct output or not.
https://jsfiddle.net/nirajrajgor/b4kvyx94/

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. I think its something to do with how I set my media queries breakpoints because when I scale the browser from min-width 1200px (desktop) to 320px (mobile), it i lose the height. Here is my media queries setting. https://jsfiddle.net/xhcr3sjm/

Comment: Your media query code is too much messy to understand.
I think u didnt check out the external resources i have used in my fiddle.
I didnt use media queries at all and still it is responsive.
I have that full code which i wrote on jsfiddle and all the external files are CDN so if u want that code then just comment your email id, i will mail u code.

Comment: Ok. When I get off of work I'll take a look at it.